# What's the different between args and &args?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my code snip

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void change(int a[]){
        printf("%p\n",&a);
    }

   int main(){
       int b[] = {1,2} ;
       printf("%p\n",&b);
       change(b);
       return 0;
   }
```

I run it and it get the result following

```
    0x7fff5def1c60
    0x7fff5def1c38
```

As we can see the actual parameter address is defferent from the formal parameter address
Then I edited my following

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void change(int a[]){
        printf("%p\n",a);
    }

    int main(){
        int b[] = {1,2} ;
        printf("%p\n",b);
        change(b);
        return 0;
    }
```

Then I get the results

```
    0x7fff56501c60
    0x7fff56501c60
```

So it seems that the actual parameter and the formal parameter have the same address.
I am confused that what's the different between &a and a（a is a array）,and why I get the different address from the first snippet?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't think that the answers so far stress it enough, I'll give another answer:

There is no difference between `b` and `&b`, if `b` is an **array**. An array is almost like a pointer, but not 100%. A pointer is a variable that stores an address, as you know. So when you create a pointer `p`, you create a new variable and then assign some address to it. Now the pointer variable `p` has an address, and it's value is also an address. You can do three things with it:
 - Get `p`s address with `&p`
 - Get `p`s value with `p`
 - Get `p`s dereferenced value with `*p`

With an array `ar`, it is different. It acts like a pointer, but it is **not** a distinct variable where an adress is stored! By creating an array, you just allocate the memory for the elements you want to store, but **not** for a variable that stores the address of these elements. The variable `ar` just 'stands for' the address of the first element, but it is not saved somewhere in an extra space; the compiler makes sure to translate `ar` to the memory of the first element - this is important to understand. So what you can do with it is:
 - Get `ar`s address with `&ar` **or** with `ar`
 - Get `ar`s value with `ar[0]`

This is the reason why in your `change` function, `int a[]` is the same as `int *a` but in your main function, `int b[]` is **not** the same as `int *b`. The latter allocates memory for an address, while the first just creates memory for a specified amount of elements, and just uses `b` as a placeholder for the first address of these elements - there is **no** extra memory allocated for the first element's address, as it would be with a pointer.

This is also the reason why in `main`, you can't do `b = some_pointer`, but you can do it in `change` - because one is a pointer that has memory allocated and thus can change it's value like every other variable, and the other one is just a placeholder for it's first element and thus cannot change it's value.

I hope now it is clear why `&b` is the same as `b` - Since `b` is not a distinct variable with a place in memory, you cannot ask for it's address - it will just give you the address that `b` stand for anyway.

Comment: Your answer helps me to comprehend the question more deeply,thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
printf("%p\n",&b);
```

you are printing the address to the first array cell.

In:

```
change(b);
```

and specifically in:

```
void change(int a[]){
    printf("%p\n",&a);
}
```

you are printing the address of the variable `a` which in itself is a decayed pointer. So it is semantically equivalent to:

```
void change(int* a){
    printf("%p\n",&a);
}
```

To retrieve the array first cell you would need to write the function as:

```
void change(int* a){
    printf("%p\n", a);
    //            ^^
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `int *a`.

Comment: Hi,I understande it from your answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `a` is the starting address of the memory where to store `array[1, 2]`. 
Please also think of `a` is a variable that stores the array address. A variable means itself is somewhere in the memory. So `&a` is the address of the variable `a`. All in all, address `&a` in memory stores the address of the `array[1,2]`.

In your first case, you are passing the address of variable `b` to function `change` so that the function variable `a` stores the address of variable `b`. But `&a` is the address of `a` not the content of `a`. That's the reason cause the difference.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,I understand it,In my function change(int a[])    a     store the array address but the      &a      points to the address of variable a.

Answer (score 1):

In `main()`, b is an array which size if derived from the initialisation, and `&b` denotes the adress of the array.

In `change()`, a is an array of unknown size, which as parameter is handled as a pointer.  `&a` is the adress of this pointer.

In the second version of your code, without the `&` you refer in both case to the value of the pointer.

Here the relevant extracts from the C11 standard:

> **6.5.3 Unary operators, pt 3:** The unary & operator yields the address of its operand.
>
> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators, pt 7:**  A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within
>   the [ and ] of the array type derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The "&" operator returns the address of a variable and the "%p" construct in printf returns the address of the pointer.

In your example, these calls in main() are equivalent:

```
    printf("%p\n",b);
    printf("%p\n",&b);
```

Both return the memory position of b, which is 0x7fff56501c60 in your example

When you define a function, you introduce a local variable a:

```
void change(int a[]){
```

This is a pointer (equivalent to int * a) and has its own memory address.

When you call this inside the function:

```
    printf("%p\n",a);
```

you get the same as above: The address of b: The value of pointer b is copied to a and printf tells you where it points at.

However if you do this:

```
    printf("%p\n",&a);
```

Then you get the address of the local variable a, which is distinct to b. It does not matter what is inside a and in your example the value of b is not even used by function "change", you could also run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change(int a[]){
    printf("%p\n",&a);
}

int main(){
   int b[] = {1,2} ;
   printf("%p\n",&b);
   change((int *)0);
   return 0;
}
```

This runs "change" with a Nullpointer and it is still equivalent to your first example: "change" just prints out the address of the local variable a, regardless of contents.